# Facebook asks for my approval while posting image from IOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am running into some issue while posting image from iOS application which uses Facebook sdk every time i post an image from my application it asks for permission on my actual Facebook account.

here it is my function which posts image to Facebook

```
- (void) postImageToFB:(UIImage*)image
{
NSLog(@"posImagetoFB was called...");
NSData* imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"This is my drawing!", @"message",
                                imageData, @"source",
                                nil];

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                          if(error)
                          {
                              NSLog(@"erro has occured %@",error);
                          }
                          if(result)
                          {
                              NSLog(@"result is %@",result);
                          }

                      }];
}
```

and here is code i use in order to login into Facebook

```
- (void)openSession
{
    NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"user_photos",
                        nil];

    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:
 ^(FBSession *session,
   FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
     [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
 }];







 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add publish_stream permission to your array like this :

**NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"user_photos",@"publish_stream",nil];**

which will allow you to post image without asking for permission again and again.

Comment: This helps thanks but one more change that i had to make is i used openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions instead of openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions and it started working for me.